# SQL Server with more users connecting than user CALs purchased

Tags: sql-server, licensing, cal

SQL server standard 2014 and 2016:
if 10 user CALs are installed for user based licensing (not core based), and 10 of the existing users on the domain connect to the SQL server all works fine.

If my client decides to add a few users to access the SQL server without telling me, what exactly will happen?

I have tried to google this, since we are cutting the CALs / users so close to the line. People are guessing and making assumptions.

In my situation, we have an RDP server and an SQL server on a domain. But, I would like to know in general regardless of this environment.

1) Can anyone tell me (perhaps from experience) how this is policed?

- I am NOT trying to get around the licensing
- My client as asked me to NOT purchase any CALs for now and to purchase them when they need them, yet they add users all the time (New RDP users) as they usually do NOT need SQL access. However, should some of these users begin to connect I need to know how the business will be impacted if they refuse to purchase CALS until they want more than 10 users accessing.

I know this is not an ideal way to manage licenses, I just want to be prepared for the inevitable.
Thank you,

M.

Comment: IMHO Licensing issues should be solved with the aid of Microsoft or with the aid/assistance of a Microsoft Partner.